# Making a follower count system in Python

Tags: python, django

I successfully made a post counter on what is basically my knock-off of Twitter that I'm building, but I can't get the follower count to work.

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.get_object()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['total_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(author=user).count()
        context['total_followers'] = Follower.objects.filter(followed_by=id).count() 
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            context['you_follow'] = Follower.objects.filter(following=user, followed_by=self.request.user).exists()
        return context
```

model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="profile"
    )
    image = ImageField(upload_to='profiles')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Create a new Profile() object when a Django User is created."""
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: because you wrote id instead of user?

Comment: Please share the related models.

Comment: i have tryed id and user, neither work.

Comment: Note that `id` is a builtin function https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id You are passing a function to the equality operator, which would return false.

Comment: @AlyssaMcWilliams: you did not share the following/follower system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed to use followed_by as the user said above, when I was bringing it over to my profile page I had `{{ total_follower }}` instead of `{{ total_followers }}`

embarrassing syntax mistake, thank you.